# AWS cli is giving "expected string or bytes-like object"

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli, minio

We are using miniO as a proxy, to connect to s3.

aws s3 ls --endpoint-url http://xxx-s3-proxy-xx.xx.xx.xxx.com is giving the below response

```
expected string or bytes-like object
```

What does this mean? any pointers would help